# proxies not working on Macbook

Tags: proxy, macbook-pro, socks-proxy, http-proxy

I have both http and socks5 proxies but after I set them up and authenticate, they don't work.

With the http proxy I do have internet access but nothing changes - still my old IP, not the one of the proxy. 
With SOCKS5 proxies, I don't have any internet connection.

I double-checked with the provider and the proxies are fine. 
I tried to contact Apple Support but apparently this is outside of their scope.

Any ideas what can be causing the issue? 
I even tried disabling the firewall on the router but no succcess.

Comment: Are these proxies running on your MacBook or are they on your network like your firewall?

Comment: I set them up in the network settings on my Macbook. I just mentioned the firewall as I thought that might be a possible reason..

Comment: Not what I asked.  Did you install these proxies yourself? Where are they physically?  Your Macbook or another server on the network?  Do you have control over these proxies?

Comment: I don't. I bought them online, the servers are in Germany and USA. 
Interesting thing to mention.. when I connect to my mobile hotspot, the proxies work. Which makes me think even more that something must be messing with the proxies in the router.

Comment: I’m trying to get a layout of the land.  But the fact they work with your mobile hotspot and not when on your network says something...it’s not related to your a Mac.  Now you have to look closer at your router.

Comment: yes, makes sense. Do you think forwarding the proxies' port would help?